# PageMethods not calling method

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, pagemethods

I have setup a page so that when a link is clicked it calls a JavaScript function which calls a Page Method.  This works perfectly on our development and staging sites but does not work on our live site.  There is no error being generated, it just doesn't call the method.  I do have the script manager tag on the page and "EnablePageMethods" is set to true.  Does anyone have any ideas.  Thank you in advance for any help that maybe offered.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function RequestAQuote_Click(ctti) {
        PageMethods.RecordClickThrough(ctti);
    }
</script>


[WebMethod]
public static void RecordClickThrough(int clickThroughTrackedId)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["globalair"].ToString()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("seo.spRecordClickThroughs", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClickThroughsTrackedId", clickThroughTrackedId);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLog(ex.ToString(), "RecordClickThrough");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well there should be some behavior after all. Does the code enter the RequestAQuote_Click function. Is HTTP request fired?

Comment: Yes, it does enter the RequestAQuote_Click function but it never calls the RecordClickThrough method.  I do not see any errors being generated.  I do not see any sign of the HTTP request being fired.

Comment: you may step into the javascript method with the debugger maybe

Comment: I tried that and it looks like it's executing the page method but it doesn't really.